# Pass jQuery Variable into ASP.NET Code Behind Using HiddenField

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm experiencing problems passing the physical size of a div (height and width) into an ASP.NET variable using a hidden field and jQuery.

This is my code, but it is not working:

```
$("<%=hfAdvertHeight.ClientID %>").val($("#Advert_Container").attr("height"));
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Missing the ID selector (#)

Answer (score 0):

The code should include the id selector `#`

```
$("#<%=hfAdvertHeight.ClientID %>").val($("#Advert_Container").attr("height"));
```

If you are performing this action on page load be sure to wrap your code in the `ready` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%=hfAdvertHeight.ClientID %>").val($("#Advert_Container").height());
});
```

Also notice that instead of retrieving the height attribute via `attr` it can be retrieved easier using `.height()`.

Comment: I have made that change, thankyou, however its still not working - I must have a error somewhere else. I am collecting the value in code behind like this: "string advertHeight = hfAdvertHeight.Value;", in the Page_Load(). Is this wrong?

Comment: Try wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function(){/*code here*/});`. This will ensure that the element has been loaded on the DOM.

Comment: The code is in that function already. It must be a problem with setting the hidden text box value because when i debug in VS, the value field is empty :(

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the # before the hidden field name:

```
$("#<%=hfAdvertHeight.ClientID %>").val($("#Advert_Container").attr("height"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "ClientIDMode="Static"" in your html as hidden control property, and then try :
 $("#hfAdvertHeight").val($("#Advert_Container").attr("height"));

Answer (score 0):

If your ASP.NET hidden field ID is "HiddenMyField", then use this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenMyField" runat="server" />

var input = $("[id$='HiddenMyField']").val();

$.ajax {
         url:.....,
         data: JSON.stringify(input),
         ...
}
```

This worked fine for me.